# How do you style the draggable box in DataGrid for Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

In Material UI's Datagrid, there is a feature called Row Ordering. In my App, when I try to drag and drop a row, the id is displayed and each character is being displayed under each other. How do I target this element to make the id all appear on one line?

[image: screenshot of my issue in which the id is being displayed vertically, each character under the other.]

I am using React 16.13.1, material-ui 4.12.4, mui/x-data-grid-pro 5.17.20

Answer (score 2):

To style that particular box you can use the `sx` prop '.MuiDataGrid-row--dragging' like so:

```
        sx={{
          '.MuiDataGrid-row--dragging': {
            wordBreak: 'normal',
          },
        }}
```

All of the sx props for DatagGrid can be found here: https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#css